# Sprite Kit pause game when lose a life

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I can not figure this out. I have a game where a player has to catch berries as they fall from the sky. When the player misses one, I want the screen to flash red and the berries to stop falling and for the game to pause for 3 seconds then resume.

```
@interface SpriteMyScene : SKScene{
    SKAction *sceneUnPaused;
    SKAction *scenePaused;   
}
```

2 methods to pause the game.

```
-(SKAction*)unpaused {
    sceneUnPaused = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        self.scene.view.paused = NO;
    }];
    return sceneUnPaused;}

    -(SKAction*)paused{
               scenePaused = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        self.scene.view.paused = YES;
    }];
    return scenePaused;
}
```

The method that creates the berries and their actions.

```
- (void)addBerry {
...
...
// Create the actions
//For each individual berry
SKAction * actionMove = ...
SKAction * gameWon = ...
SKAction * actionMoveDone = ...

SKAction *wait3Seconds = [SKAction waitForDuration:3];
SKAction * loseAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [self subtractLives];
    NSLog(@"Lost a life");
    [self vibrate];
    [self runAction:scenePaused];
    [self runAction:wait3Seconds];
    [berry removeFromParent];
    [self runAction:sceneUnPaused];

    if (_playerLives == 0){
        [[SoundManager sharedManager] stopMusic];
        SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:1.0];
        SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size andScore:_berriesKilled];
        [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];}}];

SKAction *berrie = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [berry runAction:actionMove];}];

[berry runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[berrie, gameWon, actionMove,  loseAction, actionMoveDone]]];
```

}

I don't know if this is necessary or not for you guys to help me figure out why it won't work, but here is the update method that decides on when I will spawn the berries.

```
- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast {

self.lastSpawnTimeInterval += timeSinceLast;

if (self.lastSpawnTimeInterval > [self determineAmountOfBerries]) {
self.lastSpawnTimeInterval = 0;
[self addBerry];

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When the player misses a berry, just do this:

```
[self.scene.view setPaused:YES];
```

Start an NSTimer that does the following after 3 seconds:

```
[berry removeFromParent];
[self.scene.view setPaused:NO];
```